# Python crashing EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)

Tags: python, macos

I have been trying to run a python program on Mac OS but when I do Python unexpectedly crashes and I see the following error.

Does anybody know what the cause might be?

```
Process:               Python [37466]
Path:                  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:            Python
Version:               3.7.0a2 (3.7.0a2)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        Python [37437]
Responsible:           Python [37466]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2019-01-08 13:09:03.645 +0000
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13.4 (17E199)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        0A5A1073-4F3A-57D5-EDFB-35D4F6DFCA06

Sleep/Wake UUID:       402FFBD7-FE4A-4F2C-836C-C95853521F2D

Time Awake Since Boot: 110000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       250 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000100000000-0000000100001000 [    4K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
```

.......... continued

Comment: I also get this message in the shell of idle upon startup ">>> WARNING: The version of Tcl/Tk (8.5.9) in use may be unstable.
"

Comment: The code `KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000` means python tried to access a null pointer, which in turn creates a Segmentation Fault (`SIGSEGV`/ Signal 11) because 0 is normally not mapped to a user land app. There is not much more information in that except that you are using an Alpha release (3.7.0a2) where there should already be a newer stable release like [3.7.2](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-372/). Try Updating python.